# Pointer/reference stability in boost::multi_index

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-index

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/indices.html#guarantees discusses iterator stability on rehash. However, this doesn't necessarily imply pointer and reference stability. Which operations on `boost::multi_index`, if any, invalidate pointers and references?

Comment: Anything that invalidates an iterator will also invalidate any pointers or references you hold to any internal data. The iterator is just a syntactically nice pointer after all.

Comment: Not necessarily. It's possible to both invalidate iterators without invalidating pointers and invalidate pointers without invalidating iterators. Simple iterators are commonly just a wrapper around a pointer (or sometimes even a typedef'd pointer), but fancier iterator implementations are possible.

Comment: Do you have an example of such a case? Maybe linked list?

Comment: No, even that doesn't fly, `References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated. Other references and iterators are not affected.` The docs specify specifically that the references and iterators that refer to the specific erased thing are invalidated. This implies that all other iterators AND pointers/references also remain intact.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/push_back: `All iterators, including the end() iterator, are invalidated. No references are invalidated.`

Comment: Removal invalidates the iterators/references to the removed element(s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all the indices of Boost.MultiIndex, iterators, pointers and references to an element remain valid as long as the element is not erased. In the case of hashed indices, this is in contrast with the guarantees provided by `std::unordered_map` and other standard C++ unordered associative containers, where iterator stability is not maintained upon rehashing --to restate it, if you have an iterator/pointer/reference to an element in a hashed index and then rehash the index, the iterator/pointer/reference will remain valid after that.